# How to display interactive SVG in a window on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, opengl, svg, cairo

I really like SVG, it's very nice to draw with it. So far i've made static images using Inkscape. I'd like to make them interactive though.

I did some trials, following tutorials like [this one](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/mouseover-effects-svgs). But i can see a SVG and interact with it in my web browser only. I'd like to make such things in a window on the desktop.
There are drawing kits like Cairo or OpenGL, but then i have to draw from code. It seems a more clever thing to use SVG (which was drawn using Inkscape).

What does it require to view interactive/animated SVG in a plain desktop window/canvas? I've seen some modules to convert SVG to Cairo: but is there a direct SVG intepreter for Linux?

Comment: OpenGL is just a drawing API, i.e. a bunch of functions to tell your graphics system to draw triangles and other kind of low level stuff on your screen. OpenGL IS NOT a drawing kit (you'd call these scene graphs). Just needed to say that. In the case of SVG: By combining a SVG parser (libsvg), some vector rendering system (Cairo) a DOM and a JavaScript engine you can get interactive SVGs. But that's a rather big thing to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your precisions. What is in your opinion an optimal way of producing+displaying interactive vector-graphics? The idea of producing images from code just puts me off. I was hoping for SVG to have a GPL equivalent of Flash/Air.

Comment: Producing images form code in everyday applications is a bad idea indeed. And SVG is the de-facto standard for representing vector images in an open format. However since it comes from the W3C it's designed with a DOM infrastructure in mind. So I suggest something different, and you may be put off at first: Represent your pictures as code, but not hardcoded into the program, but in some scripting language with an easy to integrate interpreter. In the same script that defines the picture you then can also add the interactivity. Good candidates I think would be Squirrel, Lua and V8 interpreters.

Comment: A related (though not the same) question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198340/good-svg-renderer-for-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the effects require javascript and cascading style-sheets, which basically means complete web rendering engine. So the easiest way is to use one, either [webkit](http://webkit.org/) or gecko (webkit has probably better support for SVG these days, plus I can't find package of gecko right now).

Comment: Ha thanks. So does this mean Webkit would provide the interpreter and the canvas to display the SVG? I've seen [this article on using Webkit on a desktop application](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/using-webkit-your-desktop-application). I hope there are Python bindings available. Thanks.

Comment: [Here's a page which summarizes levels of SVG support](http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php) in different browsers, the reason you may be having difficulty finding a package of Gecko is that they recently announced they would [drop official support for embedding for Firefox 5](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mozilla.dev.embedding/c_NMcO-N8wo/discussion).

Comment: @Benjamin -  I added the Python tag to the question due to your previous comment. Also, it obviously makes much more sense to integrate all there is needed for that than any other language.