# Good SVG renderer for Linux?

Tags: linux, svg

I'm developing some scripts to generate SVG files and I wonder what good SVG renderers exist for Linux. I know Firefox/Chrome provide SVG support (and I have the feeling that Chrome is faster at rendering) but maybe there are other standalone SVG renderers that I'm missing. I'm aware of pySVG's existence.

By good enough I mean to cover the SVG 1.1 specification as much as possible. The reason I prefer a standalone library is that my workflow is faster, as I don't have to press F5 every time.

Comment: "good" is fairly subjective, I'd suggest updating the question stating your requirements, what svg features you need, how you need to use the library, etc.

Comment: Do you mean a screen renderer, or a PDF/bitmap renderer? Any programming language preferences?

Comment: Yes, a screen renderer to create typical raster images out a standard SVG definition. Regarding the language preference, I'm using python to generate the SVG, but I'm not tied to any language for the SVG part.

Comment: [SVG-to-PNG](https://github.com/domenic/svg2png) is theoretically very good, because it uses the same renderer as Chrome, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SVG 1.1 exported by the draw.io tool is too "modern" for correct rendering by the current Batik, Cairo, qiv, or even FireFox: it seems none of them support the <foreignObject> element. However WebKit does render it properly, so to convert SVG to high-quality images  I use the "wkhtmlto..." tools from http://wkhtmltopdf.org.

`wkhtmltoimage` generates output at screen resolution and its `--zoom` switch scaled lines and text differently resulting in clipping (although opening the same SVG in Chrome and zooming performed correctly). So instead I'm using `wkhtmltopdf` to generate an intermediate pdf then rendering that as a high-resolution image with ghostscript:

```
wkhtmltopdf callbacks.svg callbacks.pdf
gs -sDEVICE=pnggray -sOutputFile=callbacks.png -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r900 callbacks.pdf
```

EDIT: a disadvantage of going via a Page Description Format is that the image file produced may have very large borders. You can experiment with paper sizes and layouts to minimise this or just auto-crop them off, e.g. with ImageMagick:

```
convert callbacks.png -trim callbacks.png
```

EDIT: FireFox 49.0.2 (Nov 2016) now renders the draw.io SVG correctly. Haven't retested Cairo or Batik. [sample draw.io file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By2CfaGRLqaBZmdEdzhqZGpDckE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I switched to ImageMagick few months ago. I found the quality of the pngs it produces higher than the ones generated using Cairo. And it even figures out the input/output extensions directly without extra parameters.

Comment: @figurebelow - I've attached a sample draw.io export: for me this still renders with "Not supported by viewer" through ImageMagick but does now work in FireFox. Does it work with your config?

Comment: You are blaming Batik for something that is not its fault. Batik is an SVG renderer. If you include HTML in a `<foreignObject>` element, then it is not Batik's responsibility to render it. You should only expect HTML to be rendered in an engine that is designed for HTML, such as a browser. Cairo is not an SVG renderer, so I don't know why you have included that either.

Comment: My mistake. I think I'm creating some confusion here. I meant I'm using ImageMagick to convert from SVG to PNG. This is not related to any SVG render in particular.

Answer (score 6):

[Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) is a very good collection of libraries/programs with support for a very large part of the SVG specification. It includes a stand-alone viewer/editor, and a command line rasterizer that can convert SVGs to raster image formats.

Comment: Finally I go on with Batik. It can be executed from the command line with a simple script and seems to have a good SVG support and active development. Thanks!

Comment: ## Nov 2016 update ## After some time I moved to Chrome as SVG renderer. Firefox does a good job as well but I find Chrome much faster. IExplorer is a decent alternative and surprisingly it comes with a native PNG exporter that is quite good too .

Answer (score 5):

You can try the command-line app **`qiv`** with the `-m -T` flags.

Comment: qiv works great , but I prefer without flags with small images.

Answer (score 2):

Qt SVG it's just 2 clicks away, if you install Qt 4.7 and select the locally installed sample project [svgviewer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/painting-svgviewer.html). Just build and run to get an animated viewport:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend WebkitGtk. This is the renderer that is used to power Safari, Chrome, and a number of other browsers. It supports rendering SVG as well as HTML.

Just `apt-get install libwebkitgt-3.0-0`. You can try it out by running `/usr/lib/webkitgtk-3.0-0/libexec/GtkLauncher`.

You can then use whatever language/bindings you like to build a GUI around the SVG renderer, including Python's Gtk bindings: http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/

Here's another good article about building desktop UIs using Webkit and pygtk bindings: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/07/how-to-build-a-desktop-wysiwyg-editor-with-webkit-and-html-5/

Comment: Where does `/usr/lib/webkitgtk-3.0-0/libexec/GtkLauncher` comes from? I have `libwebkitgtk-3.0-0` installed, but there is no such thing with it.