# Vector shape rasterization in C++

Tags: c++, graphics

I am looking for an efficient algorithm or library capable of rasterizing 2d shape defined by a set of lines and curves. So far, what I found do the reverse from what I need ,others are overkill (ImageMagic  ,Cairo) .I am interested in a compact utility. Anyone can point out to the right direction?

Comment: Why is Cairo overkill?

Comment: Because I wouldn't want to link a whole image processing sdk for the sake of just a single feature ....

Comment: Rasterization of 2d shapes is not a trivial matter, especially if it includes curves. It'd help if you could tell us about the kind of input you have, that is, how the 2d shape is defined.

Comment: 2d shape is defined by lines and bezier curves. Like those in Cairo, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rasterization of 2d shapes is not a trivial matter, especially if it includes Bézier curves. Here are some libraries you may want to try:

- [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/)
- [skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/)
- [Anti-Grain Geometry](http://www.antigrain.com/), also [here](http://code.google.com/p/agg/)
- [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)
- [mupdf](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/)
- [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com)
- [libxmi](http://www.gnu.org/software/libxmi/) (does not handle Bézier curves)

See also

- [Good SVG renderer for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198340/good-svg-renderer-for-linux)

Comment: Well ,from all this list Cairo appears to be the best candidate .

Comment: @MichaelIV, if you find a simpler one, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for "vectorization," and you can find quite a bit of it around by googling:

potrace is probably what you want:
http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(image_tracing)
http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/
http://inkscape.org/

Comment: Man ,read again, I NEED TO CONVERT FROM VECTOR SHAPE TO BITMAP.You suggested VECTORIZATION ,which is the reverse from what I need.

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  I'd suggest fleshing out the question a bit more.  What is your input data?